# Node.js control flow

Tags: javascript

I'm new with nodejs and I'm really confused in the asynchronous.

I tried with the sample code to store item to an array in a for loop:

```js
var item = {};
var array = [];
for (var j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
  item.test = j;
  array.push(item);
}
```

I expected the result of `array` to be:

```
[{test: 1}, {test: 2}, {test: 3}, {test: 4}]
```

But i got:

```
[{test: 4}, {test: 4}, {test: 4}, {test: 4}]
```

If i just push `j` to `array`, it's fine.

```
var array = [];
for(var j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
  array.push(j);
}
```

The result is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I would very appreciate any explanation why this happens.

Comment: Because you're modifying the same object inside loop. You want to create an array of objects `array.push({test: j})`, this way you will have a  new object for every key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to modify the same object while looping. Please create the object in your looping statement and push it to your array.

```js
var array = [];

for (var j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
  var item = {};
  item.test = j;
  array.push(item);
}

for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
  console.log(array[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In each iteration you're pushing the same object-instance of `item` into the array. Which ends up in an array of references to `item` which contains `test: 5` from the last assignment.

You need to create different objects in each iteration to preserve different attributes:

```js
for (var j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
   array.push({test: j});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this just by declaring item inside the scope of the loop, so it's a new object each time.

```js
const array = [];

for(let j = 1; j < 5; j++){
   var item = {test: j};
   array.push(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your item object is overriding with last item. try to reinitialize your object

Try this

```js
  

  var item = {};
  var array = [];
  for(var j =1; j<5; j++){
    item.test = j;
    array.push(item);
    item={};
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(array))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```html
var array = [];
for(var j =1; j<5; j++){
  var item = {};
  item.test = j;
  array.push(item);
}
```